# vm * the box 'hashicorp/precise64' could not be found in ubuntu

Tags: php, vagrant, vagrant-plugin

I  Install Vagrant in Ubuntu System(14.04). When i entered " vagrant up " Comment Display Following Error.

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:
vm * the box 'hashicorp/precise64' could not be found
```

Comment: Where i install vagrant inside the www Directory or Other Location.

Comment: whats your vagrant version ?

Comment: My Vagrant  Version is 1.4.3

Comment: I Also get "* The following settings shouldn't exist: box_version" Error @FrédéricHenri

Comment: When I enter "vagrant login" Comment.

Comment: why do you want to enter `vagrant login` this is only useful if you want to access protected boxes - thats not the case with the one you use

Answer (score 1):

Precise64 is Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS. Check this out [Ubuntu boxes](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

you use a pretty old version of Vagrant - I suggest you update, up to date version today is [1.8.5](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html)

since vagrant 1.8x vagrant can download boxes from [atlas](https://atlas.hashicorp.com) and supports box versioning which your current version does not support. and the Vagrantfile you are using is incompatible with your version

If you can update - go ahead and update, it will work. (note the `hashicorp/*` boxes are somehow outdated too so I would recommend you switch to `ubuntu/*` which are up to date, in your case use `ubuntu/precise64`)

If you can't update (thats not my recommendation) - you will need to manually download the box (from this [link](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/precise64/versions/20160824.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box)) and add it to your vagrant boxes (the command will be `vagrant box add --name ubuntu/precise64 <location of box file downloaded>) and remove the`box_version`from your Vagrantfile, you should be able to run`vagrant up` after this